# Azure EndPoints to SAP

Tags: azure

All

I need assistance with endpoints since this is my first time creating one. I have setup a virtual machine with SAP client installed on it. If I need port 3200 open, do I simply create an endpoint for that vm with port 3200 public / 3200 private. Additionally do I open the tcp port 3200 within the virtual machine itself also (windows firewall)?

Update: after I created an endpoint with tcp port 3200. I am getting this error when launching SAP GUI.

error: WSAEWOULDBLOCK

Answer (score 2):

You need to open the windows firewall inside VM as well.

Comment: Thank you, but yes I have done that but it doesnt seem to work. I receive an error when trying to connect to SAP app server. error: WSAEWOULDBLOCK

Comment: How would you tcping the endpoint? I tried telnet to the endpoint (port) but it couldnt connect. Firewall is disabled for all networks and still unable to telnet into the endpoint 3200. I also tried FTP which is port 21 after creating an endpoint for it.

Comment: Can you connect to the same server from somewhere else? What's the error message you got from telnet?